# Moodle functionality for automatically resuming a video at the precise timestamp where it was paused previously

Tags: moodle

In Moodle, is there a feature that allows users to pause a video during a lesson, log out, and then resume the lesson the next day with the video starting at the precise timestamp where it was paused previously? If not, is there a way to enable this functionality within Moodle?

Are there any plugins or third-party solutions that can provide this functionality?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.